# simple angularjs application run IIS

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-ui-router, web-config, iis-7.5

I am creating simple angularjs Web application, but I want to deploy my Web application in IIS, it's not working properly I am searching 3 to hours but doesn't success.
how to work this project on IIS. if you need anything else for understand I am here. I share Two images for you   understand my problem

```
if you want to test yourself run this project i edit this project as my requirement.when its run on IIS, please share with me, how to run. i really appreciate. 

https://github.com/ranjithprabhuk/Angular-Bootstrap-Dashboard
```

**README.md**

```
## npm install -g http-server
go to project the main folder where index.html exists and run the command

## http-server
run application
```

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'flash',
        //main modules
        'login', 'dashboard','staffregistration']);


    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $modalInstance) {

        //IdleScreenList
        $stateProvider
           .state('app', {
               url: '/app',
               templateUrl: 'app/common/app.html',
               controller: 'appCtrl',
               controllerAs: 'vm',
               data: {
                   pageTitle: 'Login'
               }
           });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/dashboard');
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
    }]);

    // set global configuration of application and it can be accessed by injecting appSettings in any modules
    app.constant('appSettings', appConfig);
```

**Webconfig**

```
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pTC3.jpg)

[Image Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyI1u.jpg)

Comment: What errors do you encounter in the browser console? On a sidenote: When using IIS, you shouldn't be using `http-server`. IIS serves static files out of the box, so at best running `http-server` as well, does nothing.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen thanks for your reply i share image 2 for you ,

Comment: First, it looks like some of the paths in index.html isn't correct. Also make sure paths to your angular templates/views works in production. The unexpected token error might be angular trying to load a ressource, but getting a 404 error page instead. If you're not already doing it, you should look at building/processing your application for production.

Comment: any idea how do that , for production ,

Comment: That would require a longer answer than could fit in the comment section. For angularjs I would suggest you to have a look at any tutorial on using Gulp, to bundle and process angular for production. There are a lot of ressources on that topic out there.

Comment: you Mean this code doesn't run in IIS , because Gulp have different libraries

Comment: No. IIS just handles your static files and it seems to work correctly. I don't believe your problem is related to IIS at all. You need to ensure your paths are correct.

Comment: i checked my files paths its correct , if you have Installed  IIS in your system , please download obove git code and check , I really appricate for this , because i created my project .only need for deployment :( my boss kill me :(